# Finding $AC$ given that $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Suppose quadrilateral $ABCD$ is inscribed in a circle such that $AB=4, BC=5, CD=6,$ and $DA=7.$ Find the length of $AC.$

---

I do realize that this is a repost, but the previous asker and answerers did not state a clear method as to how to do this problem. I believe Ptolemy's theorem would be useful, but I am unsure how to apply it. Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: Ptolemy's *what* would be useful?

Comment: Ptolemy's theorem, sorry for not being clear

Comment: If Ptolemy were alive, someone would have to teach him English first.

Comment: It'd help if you linked the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the cosine theorem for triangles ABC and ADC. The angles ABC and ADC add up to 180. Denote the angle ABC by $X$. Then

$$4^2+5^2 - 2*4*5\cos X=
6^2+7^2+2*6*7*\cos X,$$

so $124\cos X = -44$. So $\cos X= -44/124=-11/31$, then $AC^2=4^2+5^2-40*11/31$.